# How to get PaymentMethodNonce and deviceData on Braintree Android PayPal Vault Payment

Tags: java, android, braintree, braintree-sandbox

Am trying to implement Braintree Vault PayPal payment, the problem am facing here is getting the `paymentMethodNonce` my event listener `createdListener` to capture nonce doesn't get called using `vault`, but everything works fine using `checkout`. I can't charge customer without a `paymentMethodNonce`, please can anyone assist me.

```
mBraintreeFragment = BraintreeFragment.newInstance(this,"TOKEN_FROM_SERVER");
PayPalRequest request = new PayPalRequest().localeCode("US").billingAgreementDescription("Your agreement description");
            PayPal.requestBillingAgreement(mBraintreeFragment, request);
            mBraintreeFragment.addListener(createdListener);
            mBraintreeFragment.addListener(cancelListener);
            mBraintreeFragment.addListener(errorListener);
            DataCollector.collectDeviceData(mBraintreeFragment, new BraintreeResponseListener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String deviceData) {
                    Log.e("PayPal", deviceData);
                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(deviceData);
                        deviceDataInfo = json.getString("correlation_id");
                        Log.e("PayPal", deviceDataInfo);


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
    }

});
```

My Listeners

```
PaymentMethodNonceCreatedListener createdListener = new PaymentMethodNonceCreatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPaymentMethodNonceCreated(PaymentMethodNonce paymentMethodNonce) {
            String nonce = paymentMethodNonce.getNonce();
            Log.d("PayPal", "nonce id  " + nonce);
        }
};

 BraintreeCancelListener cancelListener = new BraintreeCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(int requestCode) {
            Log.d("CreditCard", "Braintree Error Code  " + requestCode);
        }
    };

    BraintreeErrorListener errorListener = new BraintreeErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Exception error) {
            if (error instanceof ErrorWithResponse) {
                ErrorWithResponse errorWithResponse = (ErrorWithResponse) error;
                BraintreeError cardErrors = errorWithResponse.errorFor("creditCard");
                if (cardErrors != null) {
                    List<BraintreeError> errors = cardErrors.getFieldErrors();
                    String err = Objects.requireNonNull(errors.get(0).getMessage());
                    Log.d("CreditCard", errors.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding manually your listeners to that request, it's better to just implement the interface from braintree.

For example, if you want to use the onPaymentMethodNonceCreated() just add "implements PaymentMethodNonceCreatedListener" after your class name.

```
public class "YourClass" implements PaymentMethodNonceCreatedListener {
//...
}
```

And then override the method that now the Android Studio is warning you:

```
@Override
    public void onPaymentMethodNonceCreated(PaymentMethodNonce paymentMethodNonce) {
        String nonce = paymentMethodNonce.getNonce();
        //...
    }
```

This way you can go for everyone of your listeners! Good luck!

Comment: `public class PaymentPayPalActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PaymentMethodNonceCreatedListener{//others}`, I did this but yet am not getting the paymentMethodNonce.

Comment: Then, don't add listeners yourself - "mBraintreeFragment.addListener(createdListener);" Just override the "onPaymentMethodNonceCreated" as i shown above.

Comment: @Peter ^ look up ^